# How to Sort dictionary in python

Tags: django, python-2.7

i already tried some snippet

`[{"number": "1"},{"number": "10"},{"number": "101"},{"number": "2"},{"number": "20"}]`

expected answer should be

`[{"number": "1"},{"number": "2"},{"number": "10"},{"number": "20"},{"number": "101"}]`

Comment: `sorted(the_list, key=lambda x:int(x['number']))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)